# Python Mysql Update Execute Command

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to execute the following command, setting "store"="result", for the row where the code column equals "code".

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE pjStores SET %s=%s WHERE code=%s""", (store, result, code))
```

I keep receiving the following error though:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1087'=1 WHERE code='Madness16'' at line 1")
```

Where the variables from the command were:

```
store=1087
result=1
code=Madness16
```

This is my first time really using mysql, so I am new to this. I've been stuck on this line for ~2 hours now, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I tried the following command in mysql, and it ran correctly:

```
UPDATE pjStores SET `1087`=1 WHERE code='Madness16'
```

More code as requested:

```
# Step through stores
cursor.execute("SHOW COLUMNS FROM pjStores")
stores = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT code FROM pjStores")
codes = cursor.fetchall()

for store in stores[1:]:    # Hack to skip first entry
    pj.setStore(store[0])
    for code in codes:
        result = pj.checkCode(code[0])
        cursor.execute ("""UPDATE pjStores SET %d=%s WHERE code=%s""", (store[0],     result, code[0]))
```

Comment: It is like you have a quote problem, if you look at the error (='Madness16") it is really that?

Comment: Why are you using integer for field names? 1087 should not be a field name, but an ID.

The problem is probably caused by mixing up strings and ints, but one can't be sure unless we see more code.

Comment: @JeremyD The quotes issue was just in this post, the actual error showed two single quotes instead of a double quote. I updated the post so it is formatted correctly.

Comment: @Dow I added more code as requested.

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Comment: @user589983 This is my pjStores database. Let me know if you need any more information from it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/121443/pj-stackexchange-help1.png

Comment: Paste the result of "show create table pjStores" so we can help further.

Comment: @sberry I ran that, and it returned: 
CREATE TABLE `pjStores` (
 `code` text NOT NULL,
...

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @xur17: Yes, it would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, don't need it anymore since you posted that image.  Everyone was confused because typically columns aren't named by integers.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something like this instead, (assuming this is not prone to sql injection attacks - meaning the data is trusted and not user provided)

```
...
for code in code:
    result = pj.checkCode(code[0])
    query = """UPDATE pjStores SET `%s` = %%s WHERE `code` = %%s""" % store[0]
    cursor.execute(query, (result, code[0]))
```

Comment: This won't be prone to sql injection attacks. It's a local script run by me to scrape a website.
I'm giving this a try right now, I'll report back.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem for me! Out of curiosity, was this problem occurring because the columns are titled with integers? Is it a problem for me to do this, or just not usual for integers to be used for the column names?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'` instead of `"`:

```
cursor.execute('''UPDATE pjStores SET %s=%s WHERE code=%s''', (store, result, code))
```